# How can I read my emails with clojure?

Tags: clojure

I want to parse messages from my IMAP inbox with clojure.

I know there is [clojure-mail](https://github.com/owainlewis/clojure-mail) library, but I do not have a gmail account. Thanks!

Comment: There's no shortage of IMAP libraries for Java.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy an answer with clojure using java libraries could be cool too.

Comment: @LeonidBeschastny, ...which the OP already knew about, and even mentioned in the question, but can't use on account of being gmail-only.

Comment: @leontalbot, ...well, what do you consider essential part of an answer? Using an IMAP client library from Clojure isn't exactly rocket science, but writing a good, idiomatic native wrapper is *work*, and SO isn't exactly a venue for "do my work for me for free" type questions.

Comment: Personally, I'd consider the IMAP client from Apache Commons; see http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-net/apidocs/org/apache/commons/net/imap/package-summary.html

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The Apache Commons IMAP client library is a reasonable choice. The core of [their example program](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-net/examples/mail/IMAPMail.java) is trivially replicated in well under 20 lines of Clojure, if one doesn't bother with failure handling:

```
(ns mail-client.core
  (:import [org.apache.commons.net PrintCommandListener]
            [org.apache.commons.net.imap IMAPClient]))

(defn get-mail [server username password]
  (doto (IMAPClient.)
    (.setDefaultTimeout 60000)
    (.addProtocolCommandListener (PrintCommandListener. System/out true))
    (.connect server)
    (.login username password)
    (.setSoTimeout 6000)
    (.capability)
    (.select "inbox")
    (.examine "inbox")
    (.status "inbox" (into-array String ["MESSAGES"]))
    (.logout)
    (.disconnect)))
```

Comment: Thanks! I"ve replaced `:include` by `:import`. How could I specify a port number? Thanks!

Comment: If you look at the documentation (http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-net/apidocs/org/apache/commons/net/imap/IMAPClient.html), you'll see that the `connect` methods are inherited from `org.apache.commons.net.SocketClient`, and so have a 2-argument form accepting a port number.

Comment: ...of course, if your port number is the one for a connection that goes over SSL, you'll need to use IMAPSClient instead of IMAPClient. The upstream documentation is worth being familiar with.